# Elasticsearch - Get locale specific date in Groovy script

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, groovy, inline

I need to update existing documents of a particular type with a new field. This new field should be set to the local day name of a date given by a datetime field in the document. The date time field is in the format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, is in UTC but has no explicit timezone code.

I'd like to do this with Groovy but have no Java experience. I'm guessing I need to:

1) Set the datetime to UTC locale

2) Convert to local locale (set to Europe/London) in this case

3) Get the day name from converted date and set new field (dayname) value with it

If I use the following update_by_query:

```
POST /myindex/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.dayname = Some_function(ctx._source.datetime)"
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "_type": "myDocType"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a simple way to do this with a some Groovy functions (replacing Some_function above).

Any hints would be very much appreciated!

UPDATE - Thanks to tim_yates i have the following Sense console code:

```
POST /rating/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.day = Date.parse(\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss\", ctx._source.datetime, java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC')).format('EEEE', java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone('Europe/London'))"
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "_type": "transaction"
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this generates the following error message:

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "script_exception",
            "reason": "failed to run inline script [ctx._source.day = Date.parse(\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss\", ctx._source.datetime, java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC')).format('EEEE', java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone('Europe/London'))] using lang [groovy]"
         }
      ],
      "type": "script_exception",
      "reason": "failed to run inline script [ctx._source.day = Date.parse(\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss\", ctx._source.datetime, java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC')).format('EEEE', java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone('Europe/London'))] using lang [groovy]",
      "caused_by": {
         "type": "missing_property_exception",
         "reason": "No such property: java for class: 1209ff7fb16beac3a71ff2a276ac2225f7c4505b"
      }
   },
   "status": 500
}
```

Though it does work if I remove reference to the getTimeZone - exact Sense console code as follows:

```
POST /rating/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.day = Date.parse(\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss\", ctx._source.datetime).format('EEEE')"
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "_type": "transaction"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure why the getTimeZone method is failing. I've tried "TimeZone.getTimeZone" instead of "java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone"

Comment: which Java version is running underneath? 1.8?

Comment: From what I can see in the docs it says Java 7 update 55 or later

Comment: Yeah, so it could be Java 7 or 8... There's an easier way for 8 than 7

Comment: The JVM on the ES nodes is 1.7.0_111 if that helps? I don't know, but can only assume that Goorvy will use the local JVM?

Answer (score 0):

The Groovy code (for Java 7) you will need is going to be very similar to this:

```
Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", ctx._source.datetime, TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))
    .format('EEEE', TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"))
```

Comment: Thanks! This works if I remove TimeZone from .parse and .format. But fails if I leave TimeZone in with error: No such property: TimeZone for class: 123322031df312eb7093fea2da1f852e31e1a660

Comment: Odd...  try `java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC')` and `java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone('Europe/London')`

Comment: Unfortunately no luck - I've updated my question above. Thanks for your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

OK, a bit more research allowed me to understand that tim_yates answer was correct, we just needed to whitelist the Java class required. We did this via:

nano $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/java.policy

and adding:

permission org.elasticsearch.script.ClassPermission "java.util.TimeZone";

...then restart the ES services.

Note this whitelists the class for all users, not just the ES user. See:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/modules-scripting-security.html